# Send Facebook friends notification

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-android-sdk

I want to send notification to my selected Facebook friends,According to the doc,I used following code.

```
private void sendNotification() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("href", "/testurl?param1=value1");
        params.putString("template", "This is a test message");
        /* make the API call */
        new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/notifications", params,
                HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, response.toString());
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
    }
```

I tried lot and found that facebook has blocked permission to post on friends wall so I have option to send notification to inform own activity with selected friends.
This code is not working for me.If any one has solution please share.I will really appreciate this.Thanks

Comment: error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) Only web canvas apps can send app notifications}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/)-

> Currently, only apps on Facebook.com can use App Notifications. Notifications are only surfaced on the desktop version of Facebook.com.

So you have to have a canvas app inside facebook to send the notification.

Else, there are other different ways of sharing, have a look at this article: [Sharing in Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share)

**Edit:**

Implementing `/feed` API-

```
private void publishStory() {
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if (session != null){

    // Check for publish permissions    
    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        return;
    }

    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                       .getGraphObject()
                                       .getInnerJSONObject();
            String postId = null;
            try {
                postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.i(TAG,
                    "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
            }
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                     .getApplicationContext(),
                     error.getErrorMessage(),
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity()
                         .getApplicationContext(), 
                         postId,
                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                          HttpMethod.POST, callback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use WebDialog for share Actually I have to send notification/message from my app to the frieds so I prefer Graph API

Comment: You can use the Graph API alos, use the API `/feed` and give the relevant paramters

Comment: See the article "Sharing a link using API calls" in the link i've provided in the answer, that uses the /feed api and publish feeds

Comment: I have implemented this and now gettting this error {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) You haven't enabled User Messages for this action type (624207847633662) yet. Please update your Open Graph settings in the App Dashboard}, isFromCache:false}

Comment: You are using the open graph story. Have you added any open graph action in the app settigs? I've added the code to implement simple posting.

Comment: Hi Now I want to tag my friends with stories but getting this error {Response:  responseCode: 500, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 500, errorCode: 1611075, errorType: Exception, errorMessage: These users or objects can't be tagged by your app: 100001481635713. Either they aren't developers of your app or your action hasn't been approved for tagging.}, isFromCache:false}

Comment: To tag friends, you have to use the open graph actions. The concept used for tagging is called [Mention Tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/). Read the tutorials and try to implement it.

Comment: Thanks it's almost answered One doubt I have already enabled tag option but it's not been approved yet after search I guess My app can tag friends after tag approval am I right?

Comment: Yes, after facebook approves you OG action you may tag your friends. You can also check all req etc to get your action approved here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/#actioncapabilities